# Android - Webkit : How to enable horizontal scrolling in div?

Tags: javascript, android, css, scroll

I trying to insert content into horizontal scrollable div using this code:

```
<div  id="scrolly">
              <div id="chartdiv_hourly" class="vh72" style="width:200%;">
              </div>
          </div>


#scrolly{
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**chartdiv_hourly**

```
  width: 200%;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: left;
```

Problem is that i cannot scroll horizontally on real device.

I tried to find any solution and i found:
https://github.com/davidaurelio/TouchScroll

But library seems to be obsolete, so i trying to find solution in pure CSS, is it possible?

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0):

You are using automatic overflow.

Use this:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Still without success.

Comment: give the css to the chartdiv_hourly element

Comment: rather than the scrolly div

Answer (score 0):

'scrolly' will need to have an absolute width set. Set to auto, I would expect it to just grow to fit the child content.

Comment: Your question indicated that you wanted to find a pure CSS solution.